# how do i add the init.h library in linux?

Tags: linux

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
 
 
static int __init hello_world_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Welcome to EmbeTronicX\n");
        printk(KERN_INFO "This is the Simple Module\n");
        printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Module Inserted Successfully...\n");
    return 0;
}
 
void __exit hello_world_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Module Removed Successfully...\n");
}
 
module_init(hello_world_init);
module_exit(hello_world_exit);
 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("EmbeTronicX <embetronicx@gmail.com or admin@embetronicx.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple hello world driver");
MODULE_VERSION("2:1.0");
```

This is the code

```
    obj-m += hello_world_module.o
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
 
all:
    make -C $(KDIR)  M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KDIR)  M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

This is the Makefile

when i start compiling i am getting an error saying

```
fatal error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <linux/init.h>
```

i need a brief explanation as im new to kernel programming

Comment: Do you have kenrel headers installed? Is the file `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux/init.h` actually existing? Does it find `linux/kernel.h`?

Comment: yes i have it installed

Comment: im not sure if it finds linux/kernel.h